# How do I completely remove a button in wxPython?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

EDIT: Windows, if it matters

Me:  Fairly comfortable with Python by itself, but all of my experience with UI is HTML/CSS/AJAX/PHP. Started teaching myself wxPython literally about 24 hours ago, so please be kind.

The Problem:

For my project, I'm going to need to be constantly adjusting the contents of the UI based on the data that is being examined.  I've made some headway in that direction, but I am hitting a wall when it comes to removing a button. There are two ways to approaches this, and I can't figure out how to do either.

Approach 1 is to delete the button.  This is represented in the code below, and it sort of works, but there's a big hole where the button used to be.

Approach 2 is to wipe the interface and rebuild it from scratch.  It might be overkill for this specific problem, but it is something I will need to do for my project.  No code posted because everything I try results in either no effect, the UI blanking out to dark grey, the app closing, or no effect except a small square appearing in the top left of the UI.

I get the feeling I am missing something obvious here, but google isn't helping; I'm apparently not phrasing it right, because all I get is how to do it like below, or situations completely unrelated to what I'm doing.

```
import wx

class TinkerFrame( wx.Frame ):
    
    def __init__(self):
    
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Sandbox')
        
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)  
        
        self.buttons  = {}
        
        self.buttons['one'] = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Press Me')
        self.buttons['one'].Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buttonPressed1)
        
        self.buttons['two'] = wx.Button(self.panel, label='No, Press Me!')
        self.buttons['two'].Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buttonPressed2) 
        
        self.buttons['three'] = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Don\'t Touch Me' )
        self.buttons['three'].Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buttonPressed3)

        for thisbutton in self.buttons:
            self.sizer.Add( self.buttons[thisbutton], 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5 )
            
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Show()
        
    def buttonPressed1(self, event):
        print( 'Congrats.  You can press a button.  Mom would be so proud.' )
        
    def buttonPressed2(self, event):
        print( 'Oooooo, two buttons.  Careful not to overheat your CPU!' )
        
    def buttonPressed3(self, event):
        self.buttons['one'].SetLabel( 'OW' )
        self.buttons['one'].Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buttonPressed4)
        
        self.buttons['two'].Hide()
        self.buttons['two'].Destroy()
        
        self.buttons['three'].SetLabel( 'HEY!' )
        self.buttons['three'].Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buttonPressed5)
        
    def buttonPressed4(self, event):
        print( 'You shouldn\'t oughta done that mister.' )
        
    def buttonPressed5(self, event):
        print( 'WHAT DID I SAY???' )
        
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TinkerFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In wxPython, the widget layout will reset on the resize event. You can trigger the event by resizing the window, then resizing back.

Try this code for the button handler:

```
def buttonPressed3(self, event):
    self.buttons['one'].SetLabel( 'OW' )
    self.buttons['one'].Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buttonPressed4)
    
    self.buttons['two'].Hide()
    self.buttons['two'].Destroy()
    
    self.buttons['three'].SetLabel( 'HEY!' )
    self.buttons['three'].Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buttonPressed5)
    
    sz = self.GetSize()
    self.SetSize((sz[0], sz[1]+1)) # shift height 1 pixel
    self.SetSize(sz)   # shift back
    if self.IsMaximized():
        self.Maximize(False)
        self.Maximize(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the following to the end of buttonPressed3.

```
self.sizer.Layout()
```

The forum post that contained that advice also said that self.Update() and/or self.Refresh() would be required. ("self" in this context being the wxFrame) This was not my experience but I mention it because they might be required in some situations.